# How do you find the equation of the parabola of this envelope created using two opposing sides of a pentagon?

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, partial-differential-equations

I can kind of understand how this would work with an envelope of a family of lines based on the x and y-axis themselves, but I just can't figure out how that could translate to this situation where the lines connect from the x-axis and a "random" positive slope that passes through the origin.

[image: Here is the arrangement of the envelope in a regular pentagon]

Or you could check here, if the image link doesn't work: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eizf3uxuaq

Comment: It should be noted that "it looks like a parabola" doesn't mean it actually is a parabola. It may in fact be one, but it can't be assumed so.

Comment: @Semiclassical: You're correct that this needs proof. It's "easy" to show that the curve is at worst a conic: (1) the equally-spaced points on the defining lines can be described by *linear* functions in a parameter $t$; thus, (2) the family of lines are parameterized by an equation that's *quadratic* in $t$ (and *linear* in $x$ and $y$); thus, (3) the $t$-derivative of that equation is *linear* in $t$ (and $x$ and $y$); thus, (4) eliminating $t$ leaves (at worst) a *quadratic* in $x$ and $y$, describing a conic. Done! ... Showing we get a *parabola* takes more detail, but is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I will just sketch the way to obtain your solution. First, translate and rotate the pentagon such that the vertices at $(2.6,0)$ and $(2.1,1.6)$ are on the $x$ axis, symmetric around the origin. Then these new points are at $(\pm x_0,0)$. Also, for simplicity, make the vertex of the parabola to be below the x-axis. Then the equation of the parabola becomes $$y=ax^2-b$$with $a,b>0$. You need to find out $a$ and $b$. Notice first that $$ax_0^2-b=0$$
Also, the slope of the diagonals (which you can easily calculate as $\pm m$) are tangent to the parabola at $(\pm x_0,0)$.
So $m=2ax_0$. From here on is just plug in some numbers.